# Как работает второй аргумент в Collections.sort(list1, new SalaryComporator())?

Tags: java, сортировка, compare, sortable

подскажите пожалуйста в Collections.sort(list1, new SalaryComporator()); как работает второй аргумент, который является объектом класса SalaryComporator... как происходит механизм сортировки и как Java понимает как нужно провести сортировку если мы передали просто объект, а не даже лямбду чтобы например были заданы условия которые, исполнившись дали результат, который стал бы аргументом для сорт.

```
 List<Employee1> list1 = new ArrayList<>();

 Collections.sort(list1, new SalaryComporator());
 System.out.println("Aftersorting sorting \n" + list1);

class SalaryComporator implements Comparator<Employee1> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Employee1 emp1, Employee1 emp2) {
        return emp1.salary - emp2.salary;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы передали в метод sort() объект SalaryComporator, который имплементирует Comparator. А так как он имплементирует Comparator, то у него ОБЯЗАН быть переопределен метод compare(), в котором описана логика сравнения объектов типа Employee1. И как вы видите данный метод действительно у вас переопределен:

```
@Override
    public int compare(Employee1 emp1, Employee1 emp2) {
        return emp1.salary - emp2.salary;
    }
```

А логика метода compare() проста: вернуть положительное число, если один объект больше другого. Вернуть отрицательное, если один объект меньше другого. И вернуть 0, если объекты равны. Эта логика и реализована выражением:

```
return emp1.salary - emp2.salary;
```

Соответственно, вы передаете в качестве второго параметра методу sort() ваш компаратор и Java знает, что ей логику сравнения нужно смотреть в переопределенном методе compare() вашего компаратора. И Java уверена, что метод будет переопределен, так как не переопределив метод compare() у вас бы не скомпилировался код, в котором вы создаете

```
class SalaryComporator implements Comparator<Employee1>
```

Comment: Я знаком с переопределением и темой интерфейс с его абстрактным методом, мне непонятно как работает механизм в методе сорт, ведь туда мы передали просто лист и объект класса который имплементировал компаратор и реализовал его абстрактный метод. Мне не понятно, то почему метод сорт начинает сортировать не по дефолту, а по условию которое мы задали в перезаписанном методе. Как java понимает какую сортировку надо брать ведь мы в методе сорт просто передали объект класса который имплементировал интерфейс Компаратор

Comment: Вам нужно почитать про ссылки на методы и как это реализовано в java . Вы вообще могли это сделать  через лямбду 
Collections.sort(list1, (emp1, emp2) -> emp1.salary - emp2.salary);
Писать вам тут про анонимные классы и лямбды нету смысла.  В инете море информации. А лучше всего почитать книгу Stream in Action

Comment: @Vasif по дефолту Java знает как сортировать только объекты классов, которые реализуют интерфейс Comparable. Такие классы как String, Integer - реализуют этот интерфейс и переопределеяют метод compareTO. Если вы хотите чтобы JAVA знала как "по-дефолту" сортировать ваш класс , например Employees - то вам нужно чтобы класс Employees также имплементировал Comarable. C этого момента Java знает "дефолтный порядок" для вашего класса. И вы можете передать свой список из Employees в метод sort() БЕЗ КОМПАРАТОРА. И Java отсортирует. Но вы можете передать и С Компоратором - и тогда ...

Comment: @Vasif ... "дефолтный порядок" полученный с помощью Comparable проигнорируется - и сортировка пройдет по той логике, которая расписана в Компораторе. То есть логика в методе Comparatora - более приоритетна, чем логика в Сomaparable. И она перекрывает "дефолтный порядок". Что очень удобно, потому что вы всегда, например, можете воспользоваться методом sort() чтобы передать LIST c Integers и отсортировать их по-возрастанию. Но если вам понадобится, например по-убыванию - то вам нужно вместе с List передать и компаратор с логикой "по-убыванию" - который перекроет "естественный порядок"

Answer (score 0):

Тут используется интересная техника, которая появилась ещё в C, а, может быть, и раньше, просто мы об этом не знаем.

Функция сортировки, хотя и кажется простой, на деле требует учёта разных мелочей и проверки граничных условий, поэтому написать её непросто.

Конечно, хочется, чтобы единожды написанная и отлаженная функция, работала с разными типами данных, чтобы не писать её для всех примитивных типов и для собственных классов.

В таких языках, как Haskell, Rust или F# вы можете написать обобщённую функцию (generic function), которая будет работать с данными любого типа, поддерживающими оператор *меньшее* или *больше*.

В C++, Java и C# так сделать нельзя. Мы можем написать обобщённый метод, работающий с переменными типа `T`, но мы не можем задать ограничение, что для типа должен существовать оператор `<` или `>`.

Вторая проблема, которая возникает, когда мы хотим написать универсальную функцию сортировки — порядок сортировки. Программисту может потребоваться и сортировка по возрастанию, и сортировка по убыванию. Надо ли писать две функции сортировки?

Оказывается, нет.

В C функция `qsort` получает на вход указатель на начало массива *каких-то элементов*, размер каждого элемента, их количество и функцию сравнения — компаратор.

Первые три параметра позволяют ей определить адрес начала каждого элемента, а последний является своеобразной заменой операторов `<` и `>`.

Компаратор в C получает на вход адреса двух элементов неопределённого типа `void*`. Он приводит их к тому типу, с которым умеет работать, и сравнивает.

Если компаратор возвращает +1, функция сортировки понимает, что первый элемент больше второго и меняет их местами. Для обмена она просто копирует нужное количество байт, не понимая, что там внутри.

Таким образом, мы получаем универсальную функцию сортировки, которая может сортировать и примитивные типы, и строки, и структуры любого фиксированного размера, и указатели на структуры — главное, правильно передать компаратор.

А если компаратор будет возвращать -1 вместо +1 и наоборот, то `qsort` вместо сортировки по возрастанию, упорядочит элементы по убыванию. Это такой приятный и почти бесплатный бонус.

В Java есть свои ограничения, в частности, если речь идёт о списке объектов, мы не можем складывать туда примитивные типы. В остальном всё точно также, как и в C. Есть массив ссылок, есть функция-компаратор, которая спрятана в отдельный класс, поэтому теперь это не функция, а метод.

Для чего тут интерфейс `Comparator<T>`, который надо реализовать — тема отдельного исторического экскурса. Указатели на функции, или их аналоги, существуют в разных языках программирования и выглядят совершенно по разному. Создатели Java решили, что здесь они будут такими.